# ScalaTestPlay-Plus running code before a test, but after the app has been created

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, scalatest

In ScalaTest ([+ play](https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play)) you can use the [`BeforeAndAfter`](http://doc.scalatest.org/3.0.1/#org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter) trait to run code before or after a test.
However, you cannot access the app (created using `GuiceApplicationBuilder`) when using `GuiceOneServerPerTest`.

```
Test isn't running yet so application is not available
```

How do you run some code before the test starts, but after the application is available?

Comment: Are you not able to use GuiceOneServerPerSuite?

Comment: I should have said, we wanted OneServerPerTest specifically, and for the BeforeAndAfter to run before and after each test.  This was to keep our tests separate and unable to interfere with each other, as our application is stateful.  Will have a look at moving to suites, and just having suites with a single test for the cases where tests might interfere. Thanks!